# White CSS arrow inside div

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm looking to create this white arrow that goes inside the image with the HTML you can find in the snippet in a pure CSS way, not editing any HTML code.

[image: Result desired]

```css
.foto {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 215px;
    background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,#fff 0) bottom right/10% 50% no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 50%,transparent 0%) top right/10% 50% no-repeat, url(https://s3.pagegear.co/1/contents/blog/2016/imagen_cachorro_comprimir.jpg) center/cover
}
```

```html
<div class="foto bg_fix"><img src="https://s3.pagegear.co/1/contents/blog/2016/imagen_cachorro_comprimir.jpg" itemprop="image" width="724" height="230" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: research about svg clip-path.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? I can give you the code to copy/paste but I'm not helping you that way. Hint: you can use clip-path (but it's not that well supported in all browsers). If you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: I was trying with linear-gradient, but I was able to doing it but with the white triangle pointing to the rigth. Also with borders and transform skew property but I got stuck. Svg clip-path just worked perfectly. Any other solutionbetter supported is more than welcome

Comment: post the code where the triangle is pointing to the right

Comment: @MartinBA

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,#fff 0) bottom right/10% 50% no-repeat,     linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 50%,transparent 0%) top right/10% 50% no-repeat,     url(https://s3.pagegear.co/1/contents/blog/2016/imagen_cachorro_comprimir.jpg) center/cover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to support Edge, you can get away with the `clip-path`. It's by far the easiest solution to your problem. 
You can check the support on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Also, amazingly helpful tool for this is [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/), but don't forget to read about this technique on [MDN - CSS clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

```
.foto {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 215px;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 50%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 50%, 0 0);
}
  /* first value is X, and second value is Y coordinate. Feel free to experiment with percentages according to your needs. */
```

SOLUTION 2:
Old "trick" which has much much better support => [CSS shapes](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/).
You would basically need to create a new element (which is going to be your white triangle) and then put it on top of that image. Here's a sample code for a triangle that you need:

```css
#triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid red; /* red is just for display puproses */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-left"><div>
```

Btw, you have both `background-image` and `img` tag in your html. Decide which one you want to use, and if you have problem with cropping the image, you may want to look into background position and/or [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Answer (score 0):

You can correct you gradient like below. You were almost good, simply switch the position of both making the bottom one on the top and the top on on the bottom:

```css
.foto {
    min-height: 200px;
    background:
      linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) top right/10% 50%,
      linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) bottom right/10% 50%,
        url("https://s3.pagegear.co/1/contents/blog/2016/imagen_cachorro_comprimir.jpg") center/cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="foto bg_fix" ></div>
```

Comment: Yes I achieved that also, but the solution is not responsive

Comment: @HectorLandete how it's not responsive? it's perfectly responsive since it uses % values ;)

Comment: @HectorLandete it has the same responsiveness as the solution you accepted (the clip path and not the border trick because this one is not responsive)